# Vue3: Check if event listener is bound to component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a reusable Badge component. I want to be able to add a close/delete button when an onDelete event listener is present on the component instance.

```
<template>
    <div class="flex inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-0.5 text-xs font-medium select-none" :class="[square ? '' : 'rounded-full']">
        <slot />
        <button class="cursor-pointer ml-2" @click="$emit('onDelete')">
            <XIcon class="flex-shrink-0 h-3.5 w-3.5 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { XIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/solid';

    export default {
        props: {
            color: { type: String },
            square: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        },
        components: {
            XIcon,
        },
        emits: ['onDelete'],
    };
</script>
```

If I add a v-if statement to the button, the emit event is executed immediately

```
<button v-if="$emit('onDelete')" class="cursor-pointer ml-2" @click="$emit('onDelete')">
```

I'm using Vue 3

Comment: How `onDelete emit is passed by the parent component` ? in this case only `color` and `square` are passed by parent

Comment: @Radeanu `<Badge square @onDelete="onDeleteOption(selected_option)">Test</Badge>`

Comment: Sorry, you can check if there exists `onDelete` listener in this way `v-if="$listeners.onDelete"`

Comment: But in Vue 3 `$listeners` was removed

Comment: For Vue 3 use `v-if="$attrs.onOnDelete"`

Comment: @Radeanu It's not working. The button is not showing

Comment: Can you  `console.log(this.$attrs)` in mounted to check if `onOnDelete` property exists ?

Comment: It does not exist

Comment: `this.$attrs` is empty ?

Comment: Yes, this is a log from this.$attrs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0GuP.png

Comment: I would suggest changing the title of this post FROM Vue3: Check if emit is passed to component TO: Vue3: Check if event listener is bound to component. $emit is not what is being passed to the component. I had to read through this 10 times to understand what you were after.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*UPDATE: If your component is using the new [emits option](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html) in Vue3, which is the recommended best practice from the Vue3 docs, the event listeners will not be apart of the `$attrs`. [An issue will be submitted to the Vue team for clarification and guidance on why this behaves this way](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5319).*

---

I have simplified your example above in StackBlitz to isolate the functionality you are after.

Important note, I am using Vue 3.2.26.

In Vue3 [$listeners were removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html#overview).

Event listeners are now part of `$attrs`. However simply console logging `this.$attrs` in `Badge` won't display the key you are looking for, they are within `targets` but accessible by prepending `on` to the bound event name. In your case in the `Badge` component you will use `onOnDelete`.

[image]

Complete working example with Two Badges. One will display because it has a bound event `onDelete`, the other will not due to the fact that the bound `onDelete` is not present.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-8b6exq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/components/Badge.vue

Comment: The example is working but it wasn't working in my project. The problem is `emits: ['onDelete']` in the script tags. When added `v-if="$attrs.onOnDelete"` isn't working. Without it's working

Comment: @Thore very interesting. I just verified this. You may want to consider reporting this issue to the Vue team

Comment: @TimWickstrom Did you end up creating an issue I can track?

Comment: @MaxvandeLaar I do not believe it was submitted and it is explained why here https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#emits and here https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance

Comment: I'll add a feature request now

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5319

Comment: @TimWickstrom Thanks! The proposed workaround feels just wrong to me. I hope the RFC has a chance to succeed.

Comment: Agreed. It seems very counter intuative to release, document, and promote emits, but then have it break other established functionality when used.

Answer (score 1):

Silly this is so hard to do. I ended up going to the Vue internals to look at how they determine what the event handler is. I got this code from https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/runtime-core/src/componentEmits.ts#L166 which defines the behavior of how a component emits an event and adapted it.

The below code looks at if there is a function that would be called if you invoked `emit` and returns true if there is. It's likely only compatibility with the version of Vue I took it from which as of writing this is 3.4.

This should work in theory with all event types and could be adapted further to return what ones are there and what ones aren't using the instances `emitOptions`.

```js
import { getCurrentInstance, toHandlerKey } from 'vue';
import { hyphenate, camelize } from '@vue/shared';

/**
 * Determines if the current component has a listener for a specific event
 *
 * See https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/runtime-core/src/componentEmits.ts#L166
 *
 * @param event Name of the event you wish to look for, eg: 'click'
 */
export function hasEmitListener(event) {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const props = instance.vnode.props;
    const isModelListener = event.startsWith('update:')

    let handler =
        props[toHandlerKey(event)] ||
        // also try camelCase event handler (#2249)
        props[toHandlerKey(camelize(event))];

    if (!handler && isModelListener) {
        handler = props[toHandlerKey(hyphenate(event))]
    }

    return Boolean(handler);
}
```

---

**Example code**

```js
const { getCurrentInstance, toHandlerKey } = Vue;
const { hyphenate, camelize } = Vue;

/**
 * Determines if the current component has a listener for a specific event
 *
 * See https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/runtime-core/src/componentEmits.ts#L166
 *
 * @param event Name of the event you wish to look for, eg: 'click'
 */
function hasEmitListener(event) {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const props = instance.vnode.props;
  if(!props) {
    return false;
  }
  
    const isModelListener = event.startsWith('update:')

    let handler =
        props[toHandlerKey(event)] ||
        // also try camelCase event handler (#2249)
        props[toHandlerKey(camelize(event))];

    if (!handler && isModelListener) {
        handler = props[toHandlerKey(hyphenate(event))]
    }

    return Boolean(handler);
}


const Button = {
  name: 'Button',
  inheritAttrs: false,
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      hasClick: hasEmitListener('click'),
    };
  },
  template: `
    <button v-if="hasClick" @click="$emit('click', $event)">
      Click Me! 
    </button>
    <button v-else>Nothing to do </button
  `,
};

const App = {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Button,
  },
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Button 1:
      <Button @click="() => { console.log('hello'); }"></Button>

      <br />
      Button 2:
      <Button></Button>
    </div>
  `,
};

const app = Vue.createApp({
  render: () => Vue.h(App),
});
app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.0/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My working solution for Vue 3.3

```
{
  ...
  props: {
    onRemove: {
      type: Function,
      default: undefined,
    }
  }
}
```

and for the template:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="onRemove" class="btn" @click="$emit('remove')">Remove</div>
</template>
```

eslint rule:

```
"vue/require-explicit-emits": [
  "error", {
    "allowProps": true
  }
]
```

and usage:

```
<my-button @remove="remove" />
```