# I'm using vue2.7.0 to encapsulate components. I want to use listeners or $listeners in the component, but instead I get undefined

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, jsx

```js
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LbTabs",
  props: {
    tabs: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  setup(props, { emit, attrs, listeners }) {
    const active = ref();
    onMounted(() => {
      active.value = props.tabs[0]?.name;
    });

    const handleInput = (val) => {
      active.value = val;
    };

    const isComponent = (tab) => {
      return typeof tab.content === "object";
    };
    console.log(listeners);  //undefined
    return () => (
      <el-tabs
        {...{ attrs, ...listeners }}
        value={active}
        onInput={handleInput}
      >
        {props.tabs.map((tab, index) => (
          <el-tab-pane label={tab.label} name={tab.name} key={index}>
            {isComponent(tab) ? <tab.content /> : tab.content}
          </el-tab-pane>
        ))}
      </el-tabs>
    );
  },
});
</script>
```

**listeners get undefined, This is wrong**

I'm using **vue2.7.0 **to encapsulate components. I want to use listeners or $listeners in the component, but instead I get undefined

vue3.0 listeners and attrs merge，2.7  what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

In vue 2.7, although composition api is there, you can't access `attrs` for **the implicitly passed data** as you can access in vue 3 (useAttrs / setupContext.attrs).

In vue 2.7, consider using `getCurrentInstance()` to access the current vue instance (including parent component listeners), literally "this" in vue-class-component syntax.

doc:
https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance

source code of `getCurrentInstance()`:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/main/src/v3/currentInstance.ts

### Explanation:

For developers convenience, vue is expected to provide an API to get parent context (in vue 3: useAttrs; in vue 2: $attrs, $listeners).

But, vue 2.7 is kinda in the middle of somewhere: in vue 3, `attrs` have listeners, but in vue 2.7 it doesn't; in composition API, you can't call `this.$listeners` anymore. (Google: "vue 3 listeners" to see this situation)

A workaround is, to get parent context, developer should access the parent component instance directly.

To better understand this "workaround", here are some discussions on accessing parent context OR parent component instance:

discussion:
how do you get the parent context in composition api? [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/zmx2po/how_do_you_get_the_parent_context_in_composition/)

discussion:
for using mixin, get access to the current component instance from getCurrentInstance().proxy [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/17uwgh9/how_to_access_componet_options_in_vue3_defined_in/)

In component-based architecture, all discussions mentioned this  approach: accessing parent component instance, then get parent component's "special data" (like $listeners / attrs / parent context: **the implicitly passed data**).

On the other hand, data passed explicitly are literally `props`.

usage:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const thisInstance = getCurrentInstance()

    function eh () {
      // console.log(this.$listeners)
      console.log(thisInstance.proxy.$listeners)
    }

    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

It works in vue 2.7 (I believe it works in vue 3 too, although vue 3 *has its own* `attrs` to handle **the implicitly passed data**)

More on `getCurrentInstance()`: [vue 3: Is getCurrentInstance() deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209080/vue-3-is-getcurrentinstance-deprecated)

Related:

[Check if a component has an event listener attached to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706737/check-if-a-component-has-an-event-listener-attached-to-it/77428527#77428527)

[How to remove deprecated $listeners in vue 3 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834188/how-to-remove-deprecated-listeners-in-vue-3/76192157#76192157)

[vue 3 : check if event listener is bound to component instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272335/vue3-check-if-event-listener-is-bound-to-component-instance)

---

---

[1]: how vue 2 $listeners works?
https://medium.com/@jogarcia/vues-listeners-object-79ecb2eac1f1

[2]: how `inheritAttrs: false` works?
[What are inheritAttrs: false and $attrs used for in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224091/what-are-inheritattrs-false-and-attrs-used-for-in-vue/74169018#74169018)

[3]: `$listeners` breaking changes in vue 3
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed